# in class map what is necessity of const_iterator when we have iterator?

Tags: c++, class, dictionary

I read that class map have both `const_iterator` and iterator `Typedefs` and I am interested if there is necessity of `const_iterator`. Is there anything that `const_iterator` can do and iterator cant?

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s44w4h2s.aspx)

Comment: This question would have been a **lot** more interesting if you had asked about `set` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify an element of a map via a `const_iterator`, whereas you can via an `iterator`. That is the main difference between the two.

A `const_iterator` can be obtained from `const` instances of `std::map`, or via `const` references or pointers. An `iterator` can't. This is because the member functions of `std::map` which return iterators have `const` overloads that return `const_iterator`. It is a mechanism to maintain const correctness, by not allowing modification of elements obtained from `const` instances.

```
std::map<int, int> m;
m[0] = 42;
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m.begin();
*it = 43; // OK

const std::map<int, int> cm;
cm[0] = 42;
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = cm.begin(); // ERROR
std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = cm.begin(); // OK
*it = 43; // ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks I got it I didn't know that iterator could not used in const instance.

Answer (score 0):

`const_iterator` is a more restricted version of `iterator` that does not allow modifying the values in the map. `begin()` for example is overloaded to return `const_iterator` for a `const` map, for which a modifying `iterator` by definition cannot exist.